# Incorrect syntax when setting variable equal to a number in WHEN condition of T-SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

**Context**: I have a scalar function that returns a formatted string. The type of formatting performed depends on the length `LEN()` of the string passed - this is handled with a T-SQL `CASE` statement.

**Question**: why am I getting a syntax error when setting variable, `@LengthOfString`, equal to a number?

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Relevant code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION FormatString
    (@PassedString varchar(255) NULL)
...

    DECLARE @FormattedString varchar(255)
    DECLARE @LengthOfString int = LEN(@PassedString)

    SET @FormattedString = (SELECT 
                                CASE @LengthOfString
                                    WHEN @LengthOfString = 5 
                                        THEN RETURN Format(<formatting>)
                                    WHEN ...
```

Comment: You're missing some relevant code, for example the definition and value of `@PassedString`, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and the *actual* error.

Comment: @Stu, thanks. Should be included now.

Comment: Remove `null` - this is a syntax error itself, a declared variable defaults to null;`DECLARE @LengthOfString int = len(@PassedString)`

Comment: I would also read up on the syntax of `case` as your code fragment is also a syntax error and it's *this* that's your issue.

Comment: @Stu thank you. I appreciate the help with question formatting and the question, itself.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. (And that is important from an understanding perspective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `@LengthOfString` next to the `CASE`

That statement should look like this:

```
SET @FormattedString = (SELECT CASE 
 WHEN @LengthOfString = 5 THEN RETURN Format(<formatting>)
 WHEN ...
```